# How to set custom width parameter to img tag created by tinymce?

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

How to set custom width parameter to img tag created by tinymce?

I mean when you inster the image in textarea, how to change it's width to some custom value ? Image managers config does not provide such feature so I want to modify this script, just need to know where to start

**SOLVED** 
Here is my script that I added in tinyMCE initialization block

```
imagemanager_insert_template : function(fo, enc) {return '<img src=\"' + enc.xmlEncode(fo.url) + '\" width=\"$width_mini\" height=\"' + $width_mini/(fo.custom.width/fo.custom.height) + '\"/>';
    },
```

That does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered but will post as answer so others will see that there is a solution for this problem

```
imagemanager_insert_template : function(fo, enc) {return '<img src=\"' + enc.xmlEncode(fo.url) + '\" width=\"$width_mini\" height=\"' + $width_mini/(fo.custom.width/fo.custom.height) + '\"/>';
    },
```