# Use responsive images (sizes + srcset) with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to change the img-tags generated by TinyMCE to responsive ditto when uploading an image, something like this (using [`lazysizes`](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)):

```
<img
    data-sizes="auto"
    data-src="image2.jpg"
    data-srcset="image1.jpg 300w,
                 image2.jpg 600w,
                 image3.jpg 900w"
    class="lazyload" />
```

In the deprecated (and not useful, to me) MCImageManager [you could do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889111/how-to-set-custom-width-parameter-to-img-tag-created-by-tinymce):

```
imagemanager_insert_template : '<img src="{$url}" />'
```

Is there something similar in TinyMCE? Either in the core or some of the (free) plugins? I have full control over the back end where I upload the images and I am already doing the resizing there (using [ImageSharp](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp)).

Answer (score 1):

- **Edit**: This answer works for Wordpress TinyMCE only. I didn't see that the question was not related with Wordpress.

Very old question, but I got the same problem recently.

You can hook `image_send_to_editor` filter, that is only apply to TinyMCE.

On this hook, you can apply to the output, the `wp_filter_content_tags` function that is responsible for change some markup.
Currently it adds `srcset`, `sizes`, and `loading` attributes to `img` HTML tags.

So you can use it like this:

```
/**
 * Change the image markup to include srcset and sizes
 * when using tinyMCE editor
 *
 * @param $html
 * @param $id
 * @param $alt
 * @param $title
 * @param $align
 * @param $url
 * @param $size
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
function storms_img_markup( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt, $rel ) {
    return wp_filter_content_tags( $html );
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'storms_img_markup', 10, 9 );
```

This code may require some additional validation, but it works on Wordpress 5.6

Comment: Very old question indeed, I haven't been working with TinyMCE since -17 unfortunately. `wp_filter_content_tags` sounds like it's WordPress-specific?

Comment: Yes! I didn't see that your question is not related with Wordpress! Sorry for that, friend

Comment: No worries, just wanted to know if I could mark this as the answer or not. Someone else will most likely find it helpful anyway, thanks :)